# Web crawler using python requests and getting data from JSON

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler, python-requests-html

I am trying to get some data from a page using the Requests library.

The website is: https://ion.inapi.cl/Marca/BuscarMarca.aspx

The procedure is as follows:

1. Enter a "record number" (N° Registro), for example 1236222 and press the "Search" button.
2. The results are displayed within a "Hit List" table, which shows the request for the previously entered record number.
3. Click on the hit to display the next table with more "Details".
4. The information I need to obtain is the one at the bottom of the table "Administrative Instances" (Instancias Administrativas).

I was analyzing the site and the information I need to get is in a JSON called "FindMarks" (FindMarcas) (which appears in Network > Fetch/XHR).

I have tried to extract the data from there but I can't, it gives me status code error: 500.

This is the code I was trying to extract the data and I could not manage to extract the data.

```
import requests
import json

# Ingresar el número de registro
registro = input("Ingrese el número de registro: ")

# URL y datos para la solicitud POST
url = "https://ion.inapi.cl/Marca/BuscarMarca.aspx/FindMarcas"
data = {
    "numeroRegistro": registro
}

# Realizar la solicitud POST
response = requests.post(url, json=data)

# Verificar el código de estado de la respuesta
if response.status_code == 200:
    try:
        # Decodificar la respuesta JSON
        response_json = response.json()

        # Obtener el valor de la clave "d"
        d_value = response_json['d']

        # Decodificar el valor de "d" nuevamente como JSON
        d_json = json.loads(d_value)

        # Obtener la lista de marcas
        marcas = d_json['Marcas']

        # Verificar si se encontraron marcas
        if len(marcas) > 0:
            # Obtener los datos de la primera marca encontrada
            marca = marcas[0]
            id_marca = marca['id']
            cell_values = marca['cell']
            solicitud = cell_values[0]
            registro = cell_values[1]
            clase = cell_values[2]
            signo = cell_values[3]
            titular = cell_values[4]

            # Imprimir los datos
            print(f"ID de marca: {id_marca}")
            print(f"Solicitud: {solicitud}")
            print(f"Registro: {registro}")
            print(f"Clase: {clase}")
            print(f"Signo: {signo}")
            print(f"Titular: {titular}")
        else:
            print("No se encontraron marcas para el registro ingresado.")
    except (KeyError, json.JSONDecodeError):
        print("Error al procesar la respuesta JSON.")
else:
    print(f"Error en la solicitud. Código de estado: {response.status_code}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

url1 = 'https://ion.inapi.cl/Marca/BuscarMarca.aspx/FindMarcas'
url2 = 'https://ion.inapi.cl/Marca/BuscarMarca.aspx/FindMarcaByNumeroSolicitud'

payload = {
    "Hash": "",
    "IDW": "",
    "LastNumSol": 0,
    "param1": "",
    "param10": "",
    "param11": "",
    "param12": "",
    "param13": "",
    "param14": "",
    "param15": "",
    "param16": "",
    "param17": "1",
    "param2": "1236222",
    "param3": "",
    "param4": "",
    "param5": "",
    "param6": "",
    "param7": "",
    "param8": "",
    "param9": "",
    "responseCaptcha": "este texto no se validará"
}

with requests.session() as s:
    data = json.loads(s.post(url1, json=payload).json()['d'])

    for m in data['Marcas']:
        payload = {
            "Hash": data['Hash'],
            "IDW": "",
            "numeroSolicitud": m['id']
        }
        data = json.loads(s.post(url2, json=payload).json()['d'])
        df = pd.DataFrame(data['Marca']['Instancias'])
        print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Numero  NumeroSolicitud       Fecha                                                                                                                        Observacion FechaVencimiento EstadoCodigo                                                 EstadoDescripcion
0  56092454                0  08/09/2016                                                                                                                                                            IP472                                                    Es marca nueva
1  56092456                0  23/09/2016                                                                                                                                                            IP009  Resolución de aceptación a trámite de marca (Ordena Publicación)
2  56092457                0  26/09/2016                                                                                                                                                            IP439                    Pago de publicación efectuado (Diario Oficial)
3  56092458                0  30/09/2016                                                                                                                                                            IP425                            Publicación de marca en Diario Oficial
4  56092459                0  16/11/2016                                                                                                                                                            IP012                                                      Fin de plazo
5  56092461                0  29/11/2016                                                                                                                                                            IP029                               Resolución de aceptación a registro
6  56092464                0  12/12/2016                                                                                                                                                             OFP1               Devolución de carta certificada (Oficina de partes)
7  56092467                0  16/01/2017  <p>Vistos la devoluci&oacute;n de carta certificada, se resuelve:&nbsp;Adj&uacute;ntese&nbsp;el documento a sus antecedentes.</p>                         IP664                    Resolución favorable de escrito administrativo
8  56092468                0  07/02/2017                                                                                                                                                            PAG04                                Pago - Pago final de marcas nuevas
9  56092476                0  17/02/2017                                                                                                                                                            IP158                                  Resolución de concesión de marca
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry for not answering earlier. Thanks for your answer, it worked! Mind explaining a bit? Like, why did you approach it that way? I'm curious to learn so I can use the same approach in futures tasks. Thank you!